# How to pass column name dynamically for the temp table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

`INSERT #temptable(Sno,emp_code,emp_id,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5) EXEC sp_executesql @lsql1;`

In the Above code d1,d2,d3,d4,d5 are the days in the month.. I have to pass this according to the parameters of from date and to date for a particular month..

Is there any way to sort out this?

Now when i attempt to insert more than a specified column it shows me a error

**Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.**

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Attendance_LateComing_Report1] @fdate1 varchar(20),@tdate1 varchar(20),@cmp_code varchar(20) 
AS
declare @ls varchar(max),@lsql1 nvarchar(max),@lsql2 nvarchar(max),@ls2 varchar(200)
Create table #temptable(Sno int,emp_code varchar(10),emp_id varchar(20),d1 nvarchar(10),d2 nvarchar(10),d3 nvarchar(10),d4 nvarchar(10),d5 nvarchar(10),d6 nvarchar(10),d7 nvarchar(10),d8 nvarchar(10),d9 nvarchar(10),d10 nvarchar(10),d11 nvarchar(10),d12 nvarchar(10),d13 nvarchar(10),d14 nvarchar(10),d15 nvarchar(10),d16 nvarchar(10),d17 nvarchar(10),d18 nvarchar(10),d19 nvarchar(10),d20 nvarchar(10),d21 nvarchar(10),d22 nvarchar(10),d23 nvarchar(10),d24 nvarchar(10),d25 nvarchar(10),d26 nvarchar(10),d27 nvarchar(10),d28 nvarchar(10),d29 nvarchar(10) default '',d30 nvarchar(10) default '',d31 nvarchar(10)default '' )

set  @ls = dbo.get_date(@fdate1,@tdate1)
print @ls

select @ls = dbo.get_date(@fdate1,@tdate1)
set @lsql1=N'select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Emp_Code) SNo,Emp_Code,Emp_id,'+isnull(@ls,'')+' from (
select Emp_Code,A.Emp_id,AttnDate,isnull(sum(DateDiff(MI,Start_Time2,LunchIn)),0) as Late_L
    from Hr_Master_Attendance A 
    inner join HR_Emp_Main M on A.Emp_id=M.Emp_id 
    inner join Hr_Master_Shift S on M.Company=S.Company and A.Shift=S.Shift_Code 
    where AttnDate between Convert(datetime,'''+@fdate1+''') and Convert(datetime,'''+@tdate1+''') 
    group by M.Emp_Code,A.Emp_id,AttnDate ) as a 
    pivot(sum(Late_L) for AttnDate in ('+ @ls + '))  as b'


print @lsql1
--exec (@lsql1)    
print 'Insertion Table'
set @ls2= 'd1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6'   

set @lsql2='INSERT #temptable(Sno,emp_code,emp_id,'+@ls2+') EXEC sp_executesql '+@lsql1
exec (@lsql2)
select Sno,emp_code,emp_id,isnull(d1,0)as d1,isnull(d2,0) as d2,isnull(d3,0)as d3,isnull(d4,0) as d4,isnull(d5,0) as d5,isnull(d6,0) as d6,isnull(d7,0) as d7,
isnull(d8,0)as d8,isnull(d9,0)as d9,isnull(d10,0)as d10,isnull(d11,0)as d11,isnull(d12,0)as d12,isnull(d13,0)as d13,isnull(d14,0)as d14,isnull(d15,0)as d15,
isnull(d16,0)as d16,isnull(d17,0)as d17,isnull(d18,0)as d18,isnull(d19,0)as d19,isnull(d20,0)as d20,isnull(d21,0)as d21,isnull(d22,0)as d22,isnull(d23,0)as d23,
isnull(d24,0)as d24,isnull(d25,0) as d25,isnull(d26,0)as d26,isnull(d27,0)as d27,isnull(d28,0)as d28,isnull(d29,0)as d29,isnull(d30,0)as d30,isnull(d31,0) as d31 from #temptable

-- exec [Attendance_LateComing_Report1] '2017-02-01','2017-02-06','aee'
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the form of `SQL` that you are using.  `MySQL`, `SQL-Server`, etc.

Comment: How are `d1`, `d2`, etc. chosen?  Can there be more than 5 and / or less than 5?  Please rephrase your Question to better explain the context of this data and statement.

Comment: Tables in this format (dates or periods as columns) are generally a bad idea. Anyway.. is the problem that your taget table might change columns or is the problem that your SP might return different columns? The usual approach would be to use SET FMT_ONLY to inspect the columns returned by the SP beforehad.

Comment: Tagged with `sql-server` based on `sp_executesql`

Answer (score 1):

to use dynamic parameter to insert data in SQL Server can uses code like below

```
    declare @param varchar(max)
    declare @lsql1 varchar(max)
    declare @sql varchar(max)

    set @param=',d1,d2,d3,d4,d5'
    set @sql='INSERT into #temptable(Sno,emp_code,emp_id'+@param+') EXEC sp_executesql '+@lsql1
    exec (@sql)
```

Comment: But it shows me error as ** Procedure or function 'sp_executesql' expects parameter '@statement', which was not supplied. **